# dask jobqueue unable to create client scheduler and workers

Tags: python-3.x, dask, hpc, dask-distributed

I created a job script using dask jobqueue in the following format:

```py
import dask
from dask.distributed import Client
from dask_jobqueue import PBSCluster

cluster = PBSCluster(queue='research',
                     project='DaskOnPBS',
                     local_directory='/lus/dal/hpcs_rnd/Python_Data_Analysis/Jatin/Parallel_Function_Testing/',
                     cores=24,
                     processes=2,
                     memory='10GB',
                     resource_spec='select=1:ncpus=24:mem=10GB:vntype=cray_compute')
```

when i run print(cluster.job_script()), it gives me the following output:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env bash

#PBS -N dask-worker
#PBS -q research
#PBS -A DaskOnPBS
#PBS -l select=1:ncpus=24:mem=10GB:vntype=cray_compute
#PBS -l walltime=00:30:00
JOB_ID=${PBS_JOBID%%.*}

/lus/dal/hpcs_rnd/apps/anaconda3/envs/Jatin/bin/python -m distributed.cli.dask_worker tcp://10.12.1.23:44027 --nthreads 12 --nprocs 2 --memory-limit 5.00GB --name name --nanny --death-timeout 60 --local-directory /lus/dal/hpcs_rnd/Python_Data_Analysis/Jatin/Parallel_Function_Testing/
```

After this I try to create the client interface

```py
client = Client(cluster)
print(client)
```

After printing the client, I get the below output with 0 workers, 0 Cores and 0 memory.
[image: Client interface]

I am not sure how to resolve this issue. I think that the client interface is not communicating properly with the PBS cluster/job_script. Any idea? Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

Probably either your jobs haven't yet started running or your workers are unable to connect.  I recommend looking at your worker logs to see if they give you more information.

Comment: I realized that I did not specify the number of workers. I added `cluster.scale(10)`. Thanks for the help!